# Php returning success to java after data found in database and on insert of database

Tags: java, php, json, apache

```
<?php

include("db_config.php");

$myusername = $_GET['username'];
$mypassword = $_GET['password'];



$sql="SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";

echo $sql;

$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$active=$row['active'];

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


 // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1)
{
 echo "<strong> <font size='18'>Login Success</font></strong>";
 }
 else 
 {
echo "<strong> <font size='18'>Login Failed</font></strong>";
}

?>
```

I tried response array on success.. But in java file wen I Receive it .. is showing Null.. I am using this line to receive the success

```
  success=json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
```

Also I used this in my JSON parser class to check if server returns success.

```
  if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
```

And also The login is giving Login failed.. though I enter the username present in the database

Can any1 help me??

Comment: What Java file? Do you mean JavaScript? If so, can you please show the code so we can see what it is intended to do?

Comment: Itsa java file not javascript.. In java I need to know if the user is successfully logged in.. den I need to display a message that's all

Comment: May I ask why you use PHP then, why not JSP or JSF?

Comment: I am not getting access to server directly..So Php is used for database access.

Comment: Your problem will probably be in your java code. (you can test if you get an empty page by running the php script)

Comment: It gives login failed,even wen I enter correct details in php..

Comment: BTW, your code is liable to sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what library you are using BUT using a method "getInt()" on an HTML text "Login Success/Failed" looks very wrong.

Using a "json." method on HTML data also looks very wrong.

So get your php to emit valid JSON, and, get your Java to extract the Login Success or Failed text from hte JSON.

Comment: I did in Json ..its giving null value .. can u pls help me

Comment: I figured out the query is not taken what I have entered.. but I m sending those to php

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but your php doesn't return a valid JSON, instead it returns HTML code.  Naturally when you try to parse it as JSON, you get `null`.  If your PHP is changed to this:

```
if($count==1) {
    $result['login'] == 'success';
}
else {
    $result['login'] == 'failed';
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

then you may be able to parse this in your java and use something like:

```
if("success".equals(json.getString("login")) {
    //login successful
}
```

This is not the only way to achieve this, but it should do the trick.

Comment: I tried this.. its still giving null pointer,.. can u pls help me

Comment: @user2251603 In your java code, add a debugging statement outputting _exactly_ the full content of the response - then post it here.

Comment: I figured out the query is not taken what I have entered.. but I m sending those to php

Comment: @user2251603 Also, I just noticed that I put a wrong value for `getString`.  I updated it now, but I hope that you spotted and fixed it yourself before executing the code.

Comment: @user2251603 Are you sure you're sending data with GET and not POST? Try using `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET`.  Also, your code is liable to sql injection.  You really shouldn't be using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: Its giving null pointer exceprion in this line    
     status = json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);

Comment: @user2251603 add the full response that your java code receives.

Comment: I am sending values using GET and receiving using $_GET..   ya we are using sql but it is insisted to do so..So I am doing it.

Comment: @user2251603 You can continue using mysql, but use PDO instead. And definitely use bind parameters.

Comment: Ok I am very new to this field.. Wat would u suggest me to do here,its giving Null

Comment: @user2251603 If you're new to the field, I suggest reading some documentation.  For your problem, add debugging and provide EXACTLY the full content of the response that is received in java.

Comment: I saw the query is not taking the username and password oly from java to php so inturn it is returning null..